# counting a word in array of arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm reading words from few .txt file and I wan't to know how many times each word appeared so I used array_count_values.

The problem I have is that now I have array of arrays with words that appears in all of the arrays and I would like to combined them.

for example lets say the word "once" appears in text num1 3 times and in text num2    2 times to I need an output of one array that says the word "once" appears 5 time in total.

[image: here is my array of arrays output]

my code:

```
$dir = "storage";
$title;
$auther;
$fileNum;
$words_count = array();
// Open a directory, and read its contents
foreach (glob($dir."/*.txt") as $key=>$filename) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if(substr( $line, 0, 3 ) === "#id")
        {
            $fileNum=substr( $line, 5, 3 );
        }
        if(substr( $line, 0, 6 ) === "#title")
        {
            $title=substr( $line, 8, 100 );
        }
        if(substr( $line, 0, 5 ) === "#name")
        {
            $auther=substr( $line, 8, 100 );
        }
    }
    $titleVal=-1;
    $autherVal=-2;

$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO searchtable (word, position, count) VALUES (:word , :position, :count)";

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);

    $statement->execute(array(
        'word' => $title,
        'position' => $fileNum,
        'count' => $titleVal
    ));
    $statement->execute(array(
        'word' => $auther,
        'position' => $fileNum,
        'count' => $autherVal
    ));


fclose($handle);
 }

    $temp = file_get_contents($filename);
    $temp=str_replace("'","^",$temp);
    $filtered_words = array(
    '#title',
    '#name',
    '#id',
    $title,
    $fileNum,
    $auther,
    );

    $zap = ' ';

    $filtered_text_info = str_replace($filtered_words, $zap, $temp);

    $words = preg_split('/[=.?!#--)(,;:"]+/', $filtered_text_info, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $word = array();


    for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($words); $x++) {
        $word[$x] = strtolower($words[$x]);
    }

    $finalstr=str_replace("^","'",$word);
    $final=implode(" ", $finalstr);
    $words_count[$key] = array_count_values(str_word_count($final, 1));



}

print_r($words_count);
?>
```

Comment: show your code, so we can see how you created this output

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: `array_merge` and `array_count_values`, no?

Comment: @chris85 I tried array_merge but for some reason it didn't output all the words + the wrong number of times they appeared

Comment: This is used in a loop?

Comment: @chris85 yes foreach loop

Comment: Can you provide full code example? I'd do the count outside the loop, in the loop the counts aren't ready till the end.

Comment: @chris85 I edited it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The `array_count_values` needs to be outside of the loop and your 2+ arrays all need to be generated for it to be able to work. Then you can merge and it will work.

Comment: @chris85 when I take out of the foreach loop I mean the array_count_values line, it works only for the last .txt file

Comment: Yes, you need to store all the values in the loop first.